# BS4: Disable Button with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to teach myself BS4 for a project I'm developing @work.
Basically what i have is a button group (of 2. The left one is active and the right one is disabled) What I want to do is to disable the left one and activate the right one and vice-versa on click. [Here is the code](https://jsfiddle.net/fva6Ljwr/3/):

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" id="showscore" class="btn btn-success">Show</button>
     <button type="button" id="hidescore" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Hide</button>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
function lockbutton() {
    var x = document.getElementById("#showscore").button;
    if(x.click()) {
        document.getElementById("hidescore").disabled = true;
    } else{
        document.getElementById("hidescore").disabled = false; 
    }
}
```

Don't roast me for the JS/jQuery code. I already know it's wrong. But I can't find a way to work it around.

Comment: `if(x).click()){` this is not how you write JavaScript, click event have to be assigned to your x but you can't use `click` after `if`. And secondly you are mixing native JavaScript with jQuery.

Comment: Looks like a missing closing brace there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the jQuery library included in bootstrap.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#showscore').click(function() {
        $('#hidescore').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $('#hidescore').click(function() {
        $('#showscore').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });

});
```